Pandas making all my values NaN, I don't know why
Trying to learn a bit of Pandas and now want to add a index cause prefer it over just numbers, and also wanna learn how to do it ofc, but it won't work
If I don't add the index the code works fine and I don't get NaN values and get the hex codes and RGB codes.
I haven't found any solucion yet can't find anything that resolves my problem.
Thanks in advance
When I run this code I only get the index and the rest turns into NaN, why?
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 


def colors():
        colordata = pd.DataFrame(  
         {

        "Hex code": [ 
                        "#000000",
                        "#FFFFFF",
                        "#FF0000",
                        "#00FF00",
                        "#0000FF",
                        "#FFFF00",
                        "#00FFFF",
                        "#FF00FF",
                        "#C0C0C0",
                        "#808080",
                        "#800000",
                        "#808000",
                        "#008000",
                        "#800080",
                        "#008080",
                        "#000080"
        ],

        "Decimal Code (RGB)": [ 
                        "(0,0,0)",
                        "(255,255,255)",
                        "(255,0,0)",
                        "(255,0,0)",
                        "(0,0,255)",
                        "(255,255,0)",
                        "(0,255,255)",
                        "(255,0,255)",
                        "(192,192,192)",
                        "(128,128,128)",
                        "(128,0,0)",
                        "(128,128,0)",
                        "(0,128,0)",
                        "(128,0,128)",
                        "(0,128,128)",
                        "(0,0,128)"   
        ]
                }
)
        df = pd.DataFrame(colordata, index = [   
                                "Black",
                                "White",
                                "Red", 
                                "Lime",
                                "Blue",
                                "Yellow",
                                "Cyan / Aqua",
                                "Magenta / Fuchsia",
                                "Silver",
                                "Gray",
                                "Maroon",
                                "Olive",
                                "Green",
                                "Purple",
                                "Teal",
                                "Navy" 

                        ])

        print("What color do you want information on?")
     
        print(df)
                
colors()

Here is what I get when I run the code
What color do you want information on?
                  Hex code Decimal Code (RGB)
Black                  NaN                NaN
White                  NaN                NaN
Red                    NaN                NaN
Lime                   NaN                NaN
Blue                   NaN                NaN
Yellow                 NaN                NaN
Cyan / Aqua            NaN                NaN
Magenta / Fuchsia      NaN                NaN
Silver                 NaN                NaN
Gray                   NaN                NaN
Maroon                 NaN                NaN
Olive                  NaN                NaN
Green                  NaN                NaN
Purple                 NaN                NaN
Teal                   NaN                NaN
Navy                   NaN                NaN


"If I don't add the index the code works fine" so then don't add the index values. You describe a problem that you already know how to fix?

Hi, welcome to SO! With pd.DataFrame(colordata, index=[...]) you are passing a df (i.e. colordata) to the constructor. You want to pass the original dict instead: pd.DataFrame({"Hex code": [...], "Decimal Code (RGB)": [...]}, index=[...]).

here is a working example that I tested it on my Ubuntu machine. Hope it helps!
import pandas as pd

def colors():
    colordata = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "Hex code": [
                "#000000",
                "#FFFFFF",
                "#FF0000",
                "#00FF00",
                "#0000FF",
                "#FFFF00",
                "#00FFFF",
                "#FF00FF",
                "#C0C0C0",
                "#808080",
                "#800000",
                "#808000",
                "#008000",
                "#800080",
                "#008080",
                "#000080"
            ],
            "Decimal Code (RGB)": [
                "(0,0,0)",
                "(255,255,255)",
                "(255,0,0)",
                "(0,255,0)",
                "(0,0,255)",
                "(255,255,0)",
                "(0,255,255)",
                "(255,0,255)",
                "(192,192,192)",
                "(128,128,128)",
                "(128,0,0)",
                "(128,128,0)",
                "(0,128,0)",
                "(128,0,128)",
                "(0,128,128)",
                "(0,0,128)"
            ]
        },
        index=[
            "Black",
            "White",
            "Red",
            "Lime",
            "Blue",
            "Yellow",
            "Cyan / Aqua",
            "Magenta / Fuchsia",
            "Silver",
            "Gray",
            "Maroon",
            "Olive",
            "Green",
            "Purple",
            "Teal",
            "Navy"
        ]
    )
    return colordata

df = colors()
print("What color do you want information on?")    
print(df)


This is so much easier than what I did bahaha, gonna read the rest of the comments for feedback and tips

docs

If a dict contains Series which have an index defined, it is aligned by its index. This alignment also occurs if data is a Series or a DataFrame itself.

Since colordata has no rows where its index is a colour name, the aligned values are NaN. See this miniexample:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1, 2, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1, index=[2, 0, 5])

As the index is not specified, df1 indices are [0, 1, 2]. The resultant df2 is thus:
     a
2  3.0       (3 is value in row ID 2)
0  1.0       (1 is value in row ID 0)
5  NaN       (no row ID 5)


You can't assign index when the input data is another DataFrame, here is the documentation of index method from the DataFrame function:

index (Index or array-like): Index to use for resulting frame. Will default to RangeIndex if no indexing information part of input data and no index provided.

In your code, the function will use the indices in colordata and it will create new rows for the new indices provided with NAN in it.
So, instead you can to use set_index(). This method uses one of the columns in the DataFrame as index. So first you need to make the colors part of the DataFrame, then use it here is the code:
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 


def colors():
        colordata = pd.DataFrame(  
            {
                "Hex code": [ 
                        "#000000",
                        "#FFFFFF",
                        "#FF0000",
                        "#00FF00",
                        "#0000FF"
                ],
                "Decimal Code (RGB)": [ 
                        "(0,0,0)",
                        "(255,255,255)",
                        "(255,0,0)",
                        "(255,0,0)",
                        "(0,0,255)" 
                ],
                "Color": [
                        "Black",
                        "White",
                        "Red", 
                        "Lime",
                        "Blue"
                ]
            }
        )
        df = colordata.set_index("Color")

        print("What color do you want information on?")
     
        print(df)
                
colors()

Note: You can add the column after making the DataFrame using insert().
